# python-docx import is not able to be imported even though the library is installed

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

System:
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)
Processor 1.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5
Memory 16GB
OS macOs Monterey version 12.6.1

I'm still fairly new to Python and just learned about the docx library.

I get the following error in Visual Studio Code about the docx library.
Import "docx" could not be resolved.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbpE7.png)

When I check to see the version installed I get the following:

pip3 show python-docx
Name: python-docx
Version: 0.8.11

I am able to create Word documents with one Python script even with the import issue. However, I've tried to create one using a table and this is what is causing me issues. I'm not sure if the import issue is the root cause.

When I run my script I get the following:

python3 test.py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docx/styles/styles.py:139: UserWarning: style lookup by style_id is deprecated. Use style name as key instead.
return self._get_style_id_from_style(self[style_name], style_type)`

The code causing the error:

```
Add review question table
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
table.style = 'TableGrid'
```

In researching I found I may need to import the following:
from docx.oxml.table import CT_TableStyle

And add the following to that section:
# Add review question table
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
style = CT_TableStyle()
style.name = 'TableGrid'
table.style = style

I now get the following warning:
Import "docx.oxml.table" could not be resolved

And the following error when running the script:

line 2, in 
from docx.oxml.table import CT_TableStyle
ImportError: cannot import name 'CT_TableStyle' from 'docx.oxml.table' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docx/oxml/table.py)

I also created a virtual environment and still have the same issues. If you need additional details, just let me know what to provide.

Kind regards,

Marcus